# Java tutorial on file exchange: why put the document in a jar before encryption?

Tags: java, encryption, signature, public-key-encryption

I want a user to sign a document using asymetric key.

I read the tut here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolfilex/index.html

I don't understand why the tut requested to put the doc in a jar and afterwards sign the jar. How can I do this at runtime for a user who would upload any document to sign if I need to put it in a jar ?

Is there any other tut from SUN to do a real digital signature ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is answered in the [introduction page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/sigcert/index.html) of the tutorial. You would indeed use an API rather than the JDK tools (which are designed to sign jar files) to do such a thing in an application, at runtime:

> You can use the JDK Security API, tools, or a combination to generate
>   keys and signatures and to import certificates. You can use these API
>   or tool features to securely exchange documents with others. To use
>   the *tools* for document exchange, the document(s) must be placed in a
>   JAR (Java ARchive) file, which may be created by the jar tool.

[...]

> The [Generating and Verifying Signatures](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/index.html) shows you how to use the JDK
>   Security API to sign documents.